# Using Pafy.published raises an error instead of replying with the publish date of the video

Tags: python, youtube, pafy

Code:

```
import pafy

video = pafy.new("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")
try:
    print(video.published)
except pafy.util.GdataError as e:
    print(e)
```

Output:
Youtube Error 403: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your `<a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.`

Should I make my own api key? Or is this related to YouTube's API?

Comment: Try creating your own API, otherwise, it seems the problem is pafy.

Comment: I made my own API Key and i have started using it. Thanks for the suggestion.